# In JuliaPro, how do I get registered Packages?

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I am new to JuliaPro and Julia 1.5.2, and trying to load Plots (and then Plotly(JS)) in Juno.

When I begin my script with:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("Plots")
```

which is code I copied from [https://www.math.purdue.edu/~allen450/Plotting-Tutorial.html](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eallen450/Plotting-Tutorial.html)

I got "*expected package `Plots [91a5bcdd]` to be registered*"

Hoping to clear things up, I typed Pkg.update() in the REPL, and got an error that said

*Updating registry at `C:\Users\Administrator\.julia\registries\JuliaComputingRegistry`

ERROR: expected package `Juno [e5e0dc1b]` to be registered*

As I said, I am using Juno in Atom, and a number of brief programs I wrote worked fine.  Not sure what I do to get this registering thing to clear up

Comment: Hey, can you try and open up the Julia Repl (let me know if you don't know how to get to that) and then type `]` to enter the "pkg" mode followed by `registry status`? Please let me know the results of running that command.